# Microsoft Graph API ERROR:unauthorized_client while integrate with WSO2 EI

Tags: azure-active-directory, wso2, microsoft-graph-api, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have registered APP in Azure Portal and successfully generated credentials in Microsoft Graph API. after outlookmail.init Operation in WSO2 EI, i am getting below ERROR.

ERROR:

{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'a4935017-80e8-4413-a762-780b32d8f968' was not found in the directory 'e5e67d60-adf4-40b4-883c-351dc2feef4e'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 4ecb19d5-e66b-40c1-9a15-7237a0d4c801\r\nCorrelation ID: 818ba54d-f5e5-43df-9201-96d71f598b1f\r\nTimestamp: 2021-07-08 10:14:35Z","error_codes":[700016],"timestamp":"2021-07-08 10:14:35Z","trace_id":"4ecb19d5-e66b-40c1-9a15-7237a0d4c801","correlation_id":"818ba54d-f5e5-43df-9201-96d71f598b1f","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016"}

CODE:

```
            <outlookmail.init>
            <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
            <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
            <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
            <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
            <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
            <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
            <redirectUri>{$ctx:redirectUri}</redirectUri>
            <resource>{$ctx:resource}</resource>
            <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
            <intervalTime>{$ctx:intervalTime}</intervalTime>
        </outlookmail.init>
         <log level="full"/>
```

Application in Azure Portal:

[image: Azure Portal APP]

I have seen error code [in this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes) which says like below.

```
This usually occurs when the client application isn't registered in Azure AD or isn't added to the user's Azure AD tenant. The application can prompt the user with instruction for installing the application and adding it to Azure AD
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I had a lot of similar problems with graph / wso2. Here a few things to check.

1.) check that the access/api is created by an administrator

2.) check that the api has "admin consent"

3.) i had to add a "access key" and use that one

4.) check that you use the ConfidentialClientApllication builder if you use JAVA SDK

Beside that there were a few pages that helped me to get it working.

https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/04/implement-client-credentials-flow-for-graph-java-client/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java

Regards
Martin